# Error while starting WEBrick server using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, webrick

I have an existing application with database ready I have made all the changes in database.yml and did bundle install when I am trying to do rails s to start the WEBrick server I am getting the following error

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir': File exists - /home/username/appname/app/releases/20120831125545/tmp (Errno::EEXIST)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:62:in `block in start'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `each'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `start'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Am I missing some step , Do I have to re run the migration (I have the database ready with me with data in it)
any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the tmp directory Rails uses for session store is already present. Try deleting the /tmp folder in your release directory.

Comment: Thanks Tigraine there was issue with my Logs and tmp directory